# The penalty will increase 1 if the student has in and out with a status of "0" in status

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table the log and student in log I want to select stud_id's who has 'in' and 'out' in status_log and the the status is "0".If the stud_id has in and out the penalty_count in tble student is increasing.

log

```
| stud_id | date_log  | time_log | ampm |status_log |status |
+---------+-----------+----------+------+-----------+-------+
| 123     |2015-08-19 | 07:38:34 | am   | in        | 0     |
| 123     |2015-08-19 | 07:40:34 | am   | out       | 0     |
| 5656    |2015-08-19 | 07:45:34 | am   | in        | 0     |
| 5656    |2015-08-19 | 07:47:34 | am   | out       | 0     |
| 56577   |2015-08-19 | 07:55:34 | am   | in        | 0     |
| 56577   |2015-08-19 | 07:59:34 | am   | out       | 1     |
```

The penalty will increase 1 if the student has in and out with a status of "0" in status.
log

```
|cardcode | name      | year |section    |penalty_count |
+---------+-----------+------+-----------+--------------+
| 123     |martin     | 1st  | A         | 0            |
| 5656    |neptali    | 1st  | A         | 0            |
| 56577   |juan       | 1st  | A         | 0            |
```

Please help me thankyuo.

Comment: There should be a `stud_id` in `student` table also.

Comment: the stud_id is the cardcode sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
UPDATE student 
SET penalty=penalty + 1
WHERE cardcode IN (
  SELECT l1.stud_id FROM log AS l1
  JOIN log AS l2 ON l1.stud_id=l2.stud_id AND l2.status_log = 'out' AND l2.status = 0
  WHERE l1.status_log = 'in' AND l1.status = 0
  GROUP BY l1.stud_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE student SET penalty_count = (penalty_count + 1) 
WHERE cardcode IN 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(stud_id) FROM log WHERE status_log = 'IN' AND status_log = 'OUT' 
AND status = 0 GROUP BY stud_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible without an join note you may what do add this `KEY(stud_id, status, status_log)` to the table log for even better performance.

```
update 
 penalty
set
  penalty_count = penalty_count + 1 
where 
 cardcode IN(
   select 
     stud_id
   from 
    log
   where 
    status = 0
   group by 
    stud_id
   having 
    (sum(status_log = 'in') + sum(status_log = 'out')) = 2
   order by 
    null
)
```

Note the `order by null` is to disable the default sorting (filesort in explain output) off the group by function because you dont need to sort the results when updating.

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb0dd